# Nsis Zip2Exe leaves out log named folders

Tags: nsis

Im new to Nsis so pardon me if my problem is easly solveable.

I wanted to make an exe from my freshly zipped Xampp folder (it is a webserver software).
When i zipped this with total commander every folder was at the right place.
But when i run the Zip2Exe nsis application wouldn't compress into the exe my "log" named folders EVEN if they aren't empty.

Any help would greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I had to revoke the Read only permission on the folders